# How to check if returned array has atleast two elements?

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my code:-

`Repository.DB.Table01Repository.AsQueryable().Where(item => (item.Name.Split(' ')[1] == null)).ForEach(items => _VerifyList.Add(items.Name.Trim()))`;

I split 'Name' by ' ' and if it does not have second element, I need those records.

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Split` will produce two or more elements if the `Name` contains at least one space, you can write it as follows:

```
Repository.DB.Table01Repository.AsQueryable()
    .Where(item => !item.Name.Contains(" "))
    .ForEach(items => _VerifyList.Add(items.Name.Trim()));
```

There's no need to actually perform the `Split`.

In addition, `Contains` can be mapped to SQL (it is one of the [CLR methods that map to canonical LINQ functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx)) which means that the query will execute successfully on your database. Other methods (like `Split` itself) cannot be used when querying a database through `IQueryable`, and would cause a runtime exception to be thrown.

Comment: You mean item.Name.Contains(" ") == false.

Comment: @User13839404: Yes, missed putting a `!` in front, sorry. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be wary of white space in this scenario. `"abcd ".Split().Count()` will return 2 due to the whitespace character at the end. To avoid this use the `Trim()` method to remove leading and trailing white spaces before splitting like this:

```
if(item.Name.Trim().Split() > 1) 
{
   // Do stuff
}
```

or in a Where clause:

```
.Where(item => (item.Name.Trim().Contains(" ")))
```